# "Less than or Equal to" versus "Less than" for processing

Tags: java, c, computer-science

Consider the following conditions:

```
if(a < 10)
```

and

```
if(a <= 9)
```

**Considering only `int`**.

I know these conditions serve the same purpose and the processing difference would be negligible. Yet, what can be the processing difference between the two?

Comment: The difference is huge if a is of double type :)

Comment: Then I'm preempting you with a vote to close as "too broad", which it is already, anyway.

Comment: And of course, you are asking about the Cartesian product of `Language` X `type`.

Comment: Let's consider only `int`.

Comment: What is a "processing difference" anyway?

Comment: @harold The difference in CPU processing cycles required to evaluate the condition.

Comment: @GauravBhor ok, then the answer is "it depends". What CPU? Also, consider that the source is not what is executed. Comparison with a constant is something that the compiler can trivially rewrite to use the fastest comparison.

Answer (score 5):

For `int` and `long` there is no real difference as they both deal in whole numbers.
This is because 9 is the next valid value below 10.

But for `float`, `double` and other types that can hold values smaller than a whole number there is a big difference.

Consider how these numbers would be handled by your two cases:

```
float a = 9.0
float b = 10.0
float c = 9.5
```

Edit:

In the first case `if (val < 10)`:

```
a < 10  ... true
b < 10  ... false
c < 10  ... true    <--- note this
```

Second case `if (val <= 9)`:

```
a <= 9  ... true
b <= 9  ... false
c <= 9  ... false    <--- note this
```

And this is all assuming that you end up with 'clean' numbers and rounding or division errors are not introduced such as `9.99999999999` and `10.000000000001` through any calculations you may be performing.

When comparing floating point numbers you should use that class's built-in compare method.

```
a.compare(value) < 0  ... true if 'a' is smaller than 'value'
a.compare(value) > 0  ... true if 'a' is bigger than 'value'
a.compare(value) == 0 ... true if 'a' is equal to 'value'
```

Comment: I just needed the difference for integer types. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: I started my answer when you had said you would expand the question to include both groups of numerical types. I'll leave it here as it answers the amended question but has further information for any future readers.

Comment: Note that this is why you have `{Double,Float}.compare()`

Comment: Good point, I'll throw that in too.

Answer (score 1):

For integers, there is no difference in the logical flow of the program.

But different standard solutions use one of the symbols out of tradition, and as such unofficial standards stick, it increases readability to use the "correct" symbol becasue people are used to it.

Performancewise, talking about languages that compile to Assembler, they both (on most architectures) translate to one direct processor instruction (conditional jump), making them pretty much the same.

Comment: I just needed the difference for integer types. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: @GauravBhor edited, thanks for notifying

Answer (score 1):

`<=` can be useful, if you have an "end point" rather than a "length". For example, take this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i <<= 1)
{
    gz = (~(~gz << i) | pz) & gz; // this is just an example
    go = (go << i) & po | go;
}
```

Alternatively one could write the condition as `i < 17`, or `i < 32`, which might make more sense, but either way hides the fact that 16 is the important number.

`<=` can also be dangerous, consider:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++)
{
    // anything
}
```

Why dangerous? If `x = Integer.MAX_VALUE`, this is a sneaky infinite loop. Sneaky because it doesn't look like an infinite loop. It's especially sneaky since it's probably a very rare occurrence for `x` to be `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, so it'll likely be a bug waiting to happen for a long time and then it suddenly pounces, causing unexpected negative values of `i`. For shorter types this sort of thing is probably more likely happen.

Comment: +1 Of course, none of this "helps" OP to see which is more peformant :)

Answer (score 0):

> Considering only int

There is no real difference both are equal, if you run performance test it will produce random result, resulting that both are equal.

Comment: if '9' and '10' are constants, it'll even compile to the exact same opcodes.

Comment: @MikkelLøkke do they? there are actually two different assembler instructions (at least on x86) for it

Comment: @LionC Yeah, there are also 2 separate for Java bytecode instructions aswell. However modern compilers do not simply translate instructions from source code to object code. They will often restructure the code according to the syntax tree. While it will naturally depend largely on the compiler, it is likely that any type of constant comparison will end up being identical.

Answer (score 0):

Well, even if the number is int (for float and double, <= 9 is not same as < 10), <=9 and < 10 are same meaning, but comparing with <= requires two checks < as well as == whereas < is just a less than, < seems better